# Logitech Quickcam Express not working with most programs

Tags: kernel, video, webcam, multimedia

I'm trying to get this old webcam working with Ubuntu. Cheese says "No Device Found". The Zoom application only shows "camera" as a video device, but no picture. The Camorama program is able to get a picture, so I'm not sure why 2 out of 3 programs don't work. 
lsusb shows: Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:092d Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Express / Go

If I unplug and plug it back in, dmesg gives:

```
[10381.658660] usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[10384.162530] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[10384.375509] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=092d
[10384.375512] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[10384.375514] usb 5-1: Product: Camera
[10384.375516] usb 5-1: Manufacturer:         
[10384.378582] gspca_main: spca561-2.14.0 probing 046d:092d
[10384.435577] input: spca561 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.2/usb5/5-1/input/input15
```

The device is showing up in /dev:

```
/dev/video0 -l
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Mar 29 05:31 /dev/video0
```

I thought it was a permission issue, but I'm logged in as "john" and I got this:
 cat /etc/group|grep vid
video:x:44:john
So my usercode is in the video group. 
If I run cheese from the command line, I get these errors:

```
** Message: 08:34:07.960: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:5090): cheese-CRITICAL **: 08:34:08.042: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:5090): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:34:08.042: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:5090): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:34:08.042: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5090): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:34:08.042: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5090): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:34:08.042: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5090): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:34:08.042: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Qcam is almost a 10 years old (or 20) product. permission should be ` crw-rw-r--` that's one problem and another is a driver, https://sourceforge.net/projects/qce-ga/ I am not sure it can work.

Comment: Changing permsissions didn't help.  I the driver you mentioned is for a different camera, this one is 046d:092d. If I run cheese in the command line, I get errors like this in the terminal:

Comment: I remember the time these camera became popular, people talk on the telephony 'TV Phone' the dream machine introduced 007 or sci-fi comics have come true. Logitech products are shocking like HP calculators (US design Japan made parts, good old days). [CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SPCA561](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/USB_GSPCA_SPCA561.html) Unfortunately it's obsolete, the driver had been installed kernel 2.6 to 3.6 (Ubuntu 10-12.04) and I don't know how I build this module into yours. Someone knows.